# android: Why we using Java inside Kotlin Project

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Doesn't every language have its own services and features that make it not need other languages and each has its strength.
Why for example when creating room databases **in Kotlin** Java language is mentioned?

```
val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                context.applicationContext,
                RoomDB::class.java,
                "DB"
            ).build()
```

Even in the form written entirely in Kotlin, use dependencies where **Java** mentioned in it.

```
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.3.1"
```

and on **app-level** file we use this by default

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
```

we use `JavaVersion` and `jvmTarget`

## But

On the other hand, when you create a project in Java, you can do it without Kotlin language.

I think I'm losing some sense

Comment: Kotlin runs on the Java Virtual Machine (well, on Android it runs on the Dalvik VM, but it still "first pretends" to be Java). So there will always be some "Java-isms" that you will see, such as targeting a specific JVM version or having dependencies that are actually providing Java APIs (and are not Kotlin-native).

Comment: Kotlin is still young, android foundation is still mostly Java.